# How to interpret results from Sparkling Water's GBM algorithm on classification task

Tags: scala, h2o, gbm, sparkling-water

I'm new to Sparkling Water and machine learning,

I've built GBM model with two datasets divided manually into train and test.
Task is classification with all numeric atributes (response column is converted to enum type). Code is in Scala.

```
val gbmParams = new GBMParameters()
  gbmParams._train = train
  gbmParams._valid = test
  gbmParams._response_column = "response"
  gbmParams._ntrees = 50
  gbmParams._max_depth = 6

val gbm = new GBM(gbmParams)
val gbmModel = gbm.trainModel.get
```

In model summary I get four different - one on train data and one on test data before building individual trees with prediction. The result is with predicted value as 1 in each case - this is for test data:

```
CM: Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted):
       0    1   Error       Rate
    0  0  500  1,0000  500 / 500
    1  0  300  0,0000    0 / 300
Totals 0  800  0,6250  500 / 800
```

The second confusion matrix is similar with predicted value as 1 in each case for train data. Third and Fourth confusion matrix after built trees gaves normal results with values distributed in all sections of matrix.

I need to interpret first and second matrix. Why is Sparkling Water doing that? Can I work with these results or it's just some middle step?

Thank you.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer just for readability!

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the matrix given by:

```
CM: Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted):
       0    1   Error       Rate
    0  0  500  1,0000  500 / 500
    1  0  300  0,0000    0 / 300
Totals 0  800  0,6250  500 / 800
```

We can see that all 800 observations were labelled `1`, given by the numbers in the `Totals` row.

The model being tested predicted `0` 500 times, and `1` 300 times given by the rows. That gives you an overall error of `0.625` or 62.5%.

This tells us two things:

- The data in that dataset were completely unbalanced in favour of class `1`.
- The model did a pretty bad job

Is it possible that the two initial matrices represent the summary of an untrained model, essentially picking classes at random? And the latter two matrices represent the summary of the trained model?

Comment: Thank you for reply! That was my thought aswell, unfortunately I didn't find any good source to confirm this. But it's most probable.

Comment: No, I couldn't find a source either :( hope you find an answer